# I want to return meaningful numbers with Math.random()

Tags: java, math, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: generating random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

I am using `Math.random()` in java. But always it returns less than 0. Such as 0.4454590405954

Is there a way to return meaningful numbers as what i want.

For example i want to return numbers which values are 0 to 100. How i can do it?

Comment: Multiply the result by 100...

Comment: if i multiply the number, result will a double number. but i want to generate integer type number.

Comment: Dup of [Java: generating random number in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range) (I mis-cast my close vote)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Random.nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) object to return int 0 - 100

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from
>   this random number generator's sequence.

For example

```
Random random = new Random();
int myRandom = random.nextInt(101);
// do magic
```

Comment: can you show a little code example?

Comment: @hakiko are you serious? Re-read the answer.

Comment: @ok i understand now. thanks. i'm new at java :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to get an integer from 0 to 100:

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.nextInt(101); // from 0 (inclusive) to 101 (exclusive)
```